# $|\textbf{N}_G(H):H|$ is the number of right cosets of $H$ in $G$ invariant under right multiplication (by $H$)

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation, group-actions

Here's a problem form I. Martin Isaacs *Finite Group Theory* (exercise 1A.10.(a)):

> Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$. Show that $|\textbf{N}_G(H):H|$ is the number of right cosets of $H$ in $G$ invariant under right
> multiplication by $H$.

Cihan Bahran has uploaded the solutions to the exercises of this book, and he solves this problem as follows:

> Let $\Omega$ be the set of right cosets of $H$. $H$ acts on $\Omega$
> by right multiplication. Denoting the set of fixed points by $\Omega_0$, we have:
> \begin{align*}
> \Omega_0&=\{Ha:Hah=Ha\text{ for all }h\in H\}\\
> &=\{Ha:aha^{-1}\in H\text{ for all }h\in H\}\\
> &=\{Ha:aHa^{-1}\subseteq H\}\\
> &\color{red}{=}\{Ha:H^a=H\}\\
> &=\{Ha:a\in \textbf{N}_G(H)\}\\
> &=|\textbf{N}_G(H):H|.
> \end{align*}

However, I don't understand why equality in red holds. Because $aHa^{-1}\subseteq H$ does not, in general, imply that $H^a=H$. Can someone help me understand this step of the proof or, otherwise, provide another proof for this exercise? Thanks.

Comment: What is $H^a$? I am first time seeing this notation.

Comment: @user264745, $H^a=a^{-1}Ha$ by definition.

Comment: If $H$ is normal in $G$, then $aHa^{-1}\subseteq H$ $\iff$ $aHa^{-1}= H$.

Comment: The title of the book is **Finite** *group theory*, right? My guess is that we can assume $H$ to be finite, whence $aHa^{-1}\subseteq H\Leftrightarrow H^a=H$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, I also thought that, but Martin Isaacs explicitly said $G$ was a finite group in all previous exercises, so maybe the problem was also true for infinite groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $g\in N_G(H)$, then the right coset $Hg$ is fixed by $H$. The reverse implication is not necessarily true when $H$ is infinite.

Let $G=\{ax+b\mid a,b\in\mathbb{R}\}$ be maps on the real line, and $H=\{x+n\mid n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$. Then for $g=mx$ with $m$ an integer, $Hg$ is fixed by $H$. But for most $m$  , $g\not\in N_G(H)$.